# Mac Xcode build failure issue when deploying application physical iPad device

Tags: iphone, ios, sybase, sup

I am using Xcode 4 version, and I have deployed SUP sample project developed for iOS platform in Xcode.

All the configurations I had done for running the application. The project was successfully built and run in iPhone & iPad simulators.

When I am trying to build the same with physical iPad registered, I am getting the following error.

```
[BEROR]No architectures to compile for 
   (ONLY_ACTIVE_ARCH=YES, active arch=armv7, VALID_ARCHS=armv6).
```

In the valid architecures menu i had added armv6 and armv7 also.

And at that time also am getting a number of errors saying

```
Apple Mach-O Linker Error
```

Answer (score 1):

Select your project icon, go to build settings, in the architecture option, for you valid configuration (debug/release), click the '+' button, and add "armv6". Initially it has only armv7.  Refer screen shot:

[image]

Comment: i tried this case also ..then at that time am getting a list of 63 erros that says somthing starting from 'Apple Mach-O Linker Error'

Comment: In the valid architectures section or Architecture section. These are two separate options.

Comment: In the valid architectures section.

Comment: You have to add in the architecture section. It is shown in the screen shot